# Update selected row in database without updating other rows

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update one cell in the row the user selects. So when the start button is clicked the cell in that row is updated to say 'production started'

However, when I check the database, every cell under the specific column has updated and has 'production started') instead of only the cell in the column of the row click
So the update has been applied to all cells under that column ... can anyone help ?

```
            MAcon.Open();
            OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Production] SET [Product Status]=@ProductStatus WHERE [OrderID]=@OrderID", MAcon);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductStatus", Access.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID.Text);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MAcon.Close();
```

Comment: Do all of those rows have the same `OrderID`? Is there any more code?

Comment: Is `OrderID` primary key in  `Production` table? You should update records using primary key.

Comment: No, all of the rows have different orderID's. The Order ID is the primary key in the production table